# Java/JAXB: Unmarshall XML attributes to specific Java objects

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

We got some exported data from legacy system and we need to import it to Java as objects via JAXB or something. Do you have any idea how to write any XmlAdapter for such case?
Thank you very much!

```
<document>
    <label1>Some text</label1>
    <label2 multivalue="true">
        <values count="1">
          <value>Some other text</value>
        </values>
    </label2>
</document>

<document>
    <label1 multivalue="true">
        <values count="1">
          <value>Some other text</value>
        </values>
    </label1>
    <label2>Some text</label2>
</document>
```

Progress so far:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "document")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Document {

    @XmlElement(name = "label1")
    private LabelObject label1;
    ...
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class LabelObject {

    @XmlElement(name="values")
    private ValueObject valuesObject;
    ...
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ValueObject {

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    private List<String> valueList
    ...
}
```

And then trying to unmarshall

```
Document doc = (Document) JAXBContext.newInstance(Document.class, LabelObject.class, ValueObject.class).createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new File(xmlPath));
```

But it is not working. It seems it is not trivial as it looks like :-)

Comment: What classes do you want to map this XML to?

Comment: Hello Blaise, thanx for reply.
In optimistic version I wuold like to have label1, label2, labelX as List<String> where either you can have "Some text" or "Some text #divider#Other text"
In pesimistic version String where I would tokenise the output.
Currently I am getting null when attempting to parse to String and List<String>
Thank you

Comment: Do you need to write it back out, or just read it in?

Comment: Just read in. It is part of migration process of old legacy system to new one.

Comment: @lexicore I have tried javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter to see wheter I can somehow pull the data out but got null in overridden unmarshal method :-/